# Keyboard shortcut to copy and paste code in the Node terminal/REPL?

Tags: node.js, command-line, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, read-eval-print-loop

I'd like a shortcut to copy and paste code in the Node REPL. Something similar to Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V would be ideal, but I'm not aware of any such shortcut that works.

**Question:** Is there a keyboard shortcut for copying/pasting code in the Node terminal?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Node.js REPL Commands and special keys](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_commands_and_special_keys) article the full list of supported keyboard shortcuts is in these two articles:

- [TTY keybindings](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_tty_keybindings)
- [Reverse-i-search](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_reverse_i_search)

which don't mention copy and paste support.